# Removing duplicate words from a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on removing duplicate words from an input string. I have used OrderedDict in order to do so. I have tried to implement the above using two different methods, which are nearly the same, but the output of the program is different. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Code 1:

```
    from collections import OrderedDict
    data = "the an a the"
    data="".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data))
     print(data)
```

Code 2:

```
    from collections import OrderedDict   
    data = "the an a the"
    data = "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data.split(" ")))   
    print(data)
```

The output of Code 1: "the an"
The output of Code 2: "theana"
I want to know why is this difference caused, and also, I expect to get the result as "the an a", so how to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **1st** approach:

`data="".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data))`

basically considers the variable `data` as an **iterable**. In this case, it will consider the **string** as **iterable** which contains `unique` characters. So the unique characters would be `t`,`h`,`e`,,`a`,`n` and the ordered dictionary is created with totally **6** keys.

---

In your **2nd** approach:

`data = "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data.split(" ")))`

you are ***splitting*** the string into a **list** (which means **iterable**). and the list elements are `the`, `an`, `a` and the ordered dictionary is created with **3** unique values as keys.

And in the final step you are joining them, which means just the keys will be returned as a string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: most precise explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "the an a the"
words = string1.split()
print (" ".join(sorted(set(words), key=words.index)))
```

Comment: I have got the expected output. But can you please explain the reason for these different outputs, in code 1 and code 2 that I have provided? I am new to python and therefore am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Please add explanation around your code. So that OP and future reader can easily understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`OrderedDict.fromkeys(data)`
will make dictionary from every single character inside the string "data".
result:

```
{
    '**t**': None,
    '**h**': None,
    '**e**': None,
    ...
}
```

whereas:

`OrderedDict.fromkeys(data.split(" "))`
will make a new dictionary with every word in the string (or more precisely, everything split by space) as keys of a new dictionary.

result:

```
{
    '**the**': None,
    '**an**': None,
    ...
}
```

and since you want space separated result, you should join the data back with a space,

```
" ".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data.split(" ")))
 ^ #Notice this space here.
```

Also, try to debug your code, Debugging is a major part of programming and it gives much deeper understanding of the code as well.